# Aggregate in django with decimal field

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate, djongo

I applied aggregate sum on an integer field and it is returning as expected. But, when I apply it on decimal field it is returning 0. My model:

```
class Sales (models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, default=None)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My query:

```
sales_stats = Sales.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

When I print the sales_stats it returns 0:

```
{'price__sum': Decimal('0')}
```

NOTE: there are values in price that are greater than 0. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you use default=Decimal("0.0") for price field?
Otherwise in aggregation should be used COALESCE replacing None with 0.0

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing price field from DecimalField to FloatField in models. But, this is only a quick fix. Still open for solutions.